# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.mnemonic'

Tags: python, cryptography

I've installed cryptography to run a script written by chatgpt

pip freeze says

```
cffi==1.15.1
cryptography==38.0.4
pycparser==2.21
```

this is the script

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.mnemonic import Mnemonic
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keys import HDPrivateKey

# Ask the user for the mnemonic
mnemonic = input("Please enter your mnemonic: ")

# Create a Mnemonic object
m = Mnemonic(language="english")

# Convert the mnemonic to a seed
seed = m.to_seed(mnemonic)

# Derive the private key using the HDPrivateKey class and the desired derivation path
priv_key = HDPrivateKey.from_seed(seed, "44/314159/0")

# Output the private and public keys
print("Private key:", priv_key.private_key.hex())
print("Public key:", priv_key.public_key.public_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.HEX).decode())
```

however i get the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.mnemonic'

My main thought is that chatgpt is referring to an old version of cryptography and the current version doesn't contain mnemonic or it's a different problem?

Comment: Why would you expect a script written by chatgpt to be completely free of nonsense?

Comment: `mnemonic` could be from [this](https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic).

Answer (score 2):

Literally none of this code is correct. The `mnemonic` module doesn't exist, there's no `HDPrivateKey` class.

You can discover these things by searching our documentation https://cryptography.io/en/latest/